# How to create multiline label in collectionview in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have created collectionview and collectionviewcell. In that cell i have labels. i am getting long string and trying to show that in multiline. but not sure how to do this in colletctionview.

[image][image]

Thanks for helping

Comment: set `label.numberOfLines = 0`

Comment: @Dilan i did that in code as well as storyboard also..as attached in screenshot. but no luck :(

Comment: I don't understand why "As i understand we can't give constraints to collection items." ?

Comment: @ibnetariq can we set height and width to collection items using constraints?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by collection item. But given your first SS. Yes you can give constrain to your image and both labels

Comment: @ibnetariq for inter elements like image and label i given but there is no option for item/cell

Comment: Collection View Cell's size is decide by CollectionViewFlowLayout. Once that's decided, you components within cell will be layed out according to your constraints

Comment: @ibnetariq can you please help me for how to get multiline label in collection view

Comment: Are you setting the label's `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`?. I would hard code that to something like 280 or 300 and see if that fixes your layout. If it does, then you will want to programatically set it in your collection view's `layoutSubviews` method.

Answer (score 1):

First apply constraints to you image view like this

[image]

Second Apply constraints to label

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got some solution but not sure how to put dynamic height. By following code my width is as per screen size so label is getting in multiline. but trying to get dynamic height as per content

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
                let kWhateverHeightYouWant = 400
                return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat(kWhateverHeightYouWant))
    }
```